# Save/Read Bitmap in internal storage doesn't work

Tags: android, bitmap, crop

I tried to code a simple functionallity that would crop an image (stored in the drawable folder) after pressing a button, and return the cropped image in the first Activity in an imageView. 
Aftrer trying to pass the bitmap in a arraybyte through an intent that didn't work, I am now trying to save the cropped image into the internal storage and read it in the `OnActivityResult` function, however when I am done cropping I get nothing in my `ImageView`.

For the cropping I used the following library : https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/wiki

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b;
ImageView preview;
final int REQUEST_CODE_TEST = 63;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chooser);
    preview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.preview);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Cropper.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_TEST);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            String path=data.getData().toString();
            File f=new File(path,"profile.jpg");
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            preview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The crop actvity :

```
public class Cropper extends Activity {
CropImageView cropImageView;
Bitmap bitmap;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cropper);
    bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_bonnasse);
    cropImageView=(CropImageView)findViewById(R.id.cropImageView);
    cropImageView.setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.RECTANGLE);
    cropImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    Intent retour=new Intent();
    Bitmap crop=cropImageView.getCroppedImage();
    Bitmap out=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(crop, 200, 200, true);
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = cw.getDir("Profile_pic", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File mypath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");

    FileOutputStream outputStream=null;
    try{
        outputStream=new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        out.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    retour.putExtra("directory",directory.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are finishing your crop activity , you are suppose to set your result status for your parent activity , otherwise the parent activity can not detect the result code .

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

         Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getParcelableExtra("bitmap");

         preview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
```

In this figure the result code is always RESULT_CANCEL , therefore your If block does not run.

Solution :

Do not override finish() method , just use it and change your listener with this in crop activity .

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent retour=new Intent();
            Bitmap crop = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            Bitmap out=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(crop, 200, 200, true);
            retour.putExtra("bitmap", out);

            setResult(RESULT_OK, retour);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

---

In this case I just passed the bitmap into main activity , but if you are willing to save the bitmap then send it to main activity , you are suppose to save it and put it into         `retour.putExtra("directory",directory.getAbsolutePath());`
in your crop activity , then get it by `String directory = data.getStringExtra("directory");` in onActivityResult .

Although in my view the first way is better , you have a second one.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: but even after making the changesit still doesn't work, the image doesn't appear in my `imageView`

Comment: You might have a second problem . Have you saved the cropped bitmap in sd card successfully ?

Comment: The problem is your putting extra in crop activity and getting it in main activity . Check my answer that I`ve edited it .